# Confusion about the Lorentz transfornation of position

Tags: special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames

In my frame, I see a traveler moving at a constant speed in the $x$ direction. An event occurs. I then measure the position he would assign to that event, assuming we are living in the $x$ axis, to be  $X-ut$ multiplied by the gamma factor, and here comes my problem. What does this measurement even mean? Is this result only the distance between his origin and the event according to me? Or am I measuring the position for the other observer and sending it to him somehow? This confusion is because I know the length between me and the event is contracted in his frame, so why would the observer get my result and scale it up by gamma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not *measuring* the position the S' frame observer would assign to the event, but *calculating* it from the Lorentz transform
$$x'=\gamma(x-vt)$$
$x$ and $t$ are the position and time of the event in your frame of reference, the S frame. $x'$ is the position of the event (its displacement from the origin) in the S' frame, that is the frame in which the traveller is at rest (the traveller's frame, if you like).

"Or am I measuring the position for the other observer and sending it to him somehow?" No, you are calculating the position in the S' frame of the event using your (S frame) measurements and the relevant Lorentz transform.

"This confusion is because I know the length between me and the event..." Where is 'me' in the S frame? Stationary at the origin? But I'm rather confused by your last sentence in any case; length contraction has a specific meaning and it's easy to misapply the idea. I'd not try to apply it to this case until you've done some more Special Relativity.

Comment: So the lorentz transformation calculates exactly what a moving observer would measure?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The 'moving observer' is equipped with a frame of reference, with rulers and (synchronised) clocks throughout, so s(he) can measure $x'$ and $t'$ for an event wherever it takes place. I'm not keen on the term 'observer': for me its the frame of reference – the rulers and clocks – that matter.